# Why i don't have the bar over the letter R?

Tags: math-mode

Why I don't have the bar over the letter R?

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{mathtools,array,dcolumn}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
Cf = 100 - (100* {\bar{R_{j(pr)}}\over{\bar{R_{j(obs)}}}})   
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\over` is a PlainTeX command. Don't use it in a LaTeX document. Instead, use `\frac`.

Comment: Also `*` is *no* multiplication operator, you most likely want to use `\cdot` instead!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `\bar` for short lines and `\overline` for longer lines.

[image]

A separate comment: In fine math typography, a `\cdot` is generally preferred over `*` to denote multiplication.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
C_f 
&= 100 - 100\cdot\frac{\overline{R_{j(pr)}}}{\overline{R_{j(obs)}}} \\
&= 100 - 100\cdot\frac{\bar{R}_{j(pr)}}{\bar{R}_{j(obs)}}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not only preferred, `*` is something completely different.

Comment: @Skillmon - Would you prefer if I'd written "almost universally preferred" instead of just "generally preferred". (I'm not a mathematician myself, but I'm acquainted with  quite a few. Maybe that's why if I wouldn't be surprised is some mathematician, somewhere, actually preferred `*` over `\cdot` to denote multiplication rather than, say, complex conjugation...)

Comment: `*` used as a binary operator is a convolution.

Comment: @Skillmon - Thanks for setting me straight. As I said earlier, I'm not a mathematician (and it's been a long long time since I took a course in complex calculus). :-)

Answer (score 3):

Like this? Then you just messed around with the curly brackets. (Edited the over-frac-issue)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{mathtools,array,dcolumn}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
Cf = 100 - (100* \frac{\bar{R}_{j(pr)}}{\bar{R}_{j(obs)}})  
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

When using the bar-command the following brackets include the barred content. Because you just wanted the 'R' to be barred - only include the R into the brackets.

Comment: done. Replaced \over with \frac

Answer (score 3):

Apply the command only to `R`. However, I would use the`\widebar`\  command, from `mathabx`, without loading the package.

I added some other improvements: bigger parentheses, and `pr` and `obs` typed as text, not as the products of variables:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools,array,dcolumn}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
<-6> mathx5 <6-7> mathx6 <7-8> mathx7
<8-9> mathx8 <9-10> mathx9
<10-12> mathx10 <12-> mathx12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\widebar}{0}{mathx}{"73}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
C_f = 100 -\biggl (100* {\widebar{R}_{j(\text{pr})}\over{\widebar{R}_{j(\text{obs})}}}\biggr)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi :-). There is a little little mistake :). Must be `$C_{f}$` and not `$Cf$`. Best regards.

Comment: I guess you're right, and I changed the answer accordingly. Thanks, @Sebastiano!